# Can't get rid of Let'sEncrypt in Gitlab local server - SSL configuration

Tags: ssl, nginx, gitlab, ssl-certificate, gitlab-ce

I have a local GitLab server and I had it's SSL configured with Let's Encrypt. Now I changed the SSL configuration to a custom valid certificate. I did the configuration based on [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl.html#other-certificate-authorities).

The configuration in gitlab.rb seems to be correct:

```
  external_url 'https://mydomainnnn.com'
  nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
  nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/mydomainnnn.com.crt"
  nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/mydomainnnn.com.key"
```

Now I get a privacy error in Chrome browser as following:

> NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
>   Subject: mydomainnnn.com
>   Issuer: Let's Encrypt Authority X3
>   Expires on: Jan 1, 2020
>   Current date: Jan 12, 2020

It seems the Let's Encrypt SSL is still in action!
Any attempt to reconfigure and restart (both "gitlab-ctl" and the OS itself) have no desired effect.

Comment: what are the steps taken to remove the Let's Encrypt certificate? did you remove cert from /etc folder?

Comment: I commented the configs in gitlab.rb and change letsencrypte['enable'] to false. Then I removed all files in /etc/gitlab/ssl and trusted-certs and /opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs. I put my cer, pem, der and key files in /etc/gitlab/ssl and trusted-certs, and changed the config as I said in the question. Then I ran gitlab-ctl reconfigure and restart.

Comment: And there is no certbot installed on my server.